# Muons Internal Clocks and Time Dilation?

Tags: special-relativity, soft-question, time, elementary-particles

I don't get how time dilation affects the half-life of muons? Time is just a tool that is used by humans how does that affect the internal clocks of elementary particles?

Comment: *"Time is just a tool that is used by humans "* Perhaps you should re-consider this belief in light of the fact that time dilation affects fundamental particles...

Comment: Well that's what I've a problem with. Why does an elementary particle experience time at all?

Comment: I don't know what you expect anyone to say. If you have some understanding of what time "is" that implies it should not affect muons, then your understanding is in conflict with the observed behavior of the universe.

Comment: "Time is just a tool that is used by humans" Perhaps you should re-consider this belief in light of the fact that also e.g. insects and plants age.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muons are single-particle excitations (states) of the $e-\mu-\tau$ quantum field, except that these states don't have definite values of energy (they are in a superposition of states that have definite energy). Because states with different energies change at different rates, this superposition changes with time. After some time has elapsed, the superposition is different, and includes states with different particle number ($W$, $\nu$, etc.)

What determines the probability of being in the various states is the relative contribution of each state in the superposition (it's amplitude). You could broadly say that we have a state

$|\psi\rangle = a(t)|\mu\rangle + b(t)|W^-+\nu\rangle$

and the probability of having a decay is $|b(t)|^2$. What causes us to observe say, a $W^-$ rather than a $\mu$ is when the state "collapses", i.e., gets measured by a particle detector, and decoheres.

As time goes on, the $\mu$ state gets less and less probable. Now we are in a position to answer your question.

The state that the field is in depends on what reference frame you are travelling in. If you are in the rest frame of the particle, then the state evolves at a certain rate, and therefore the decay becomes more and more probable at a certain rate. In a different reference frame, that decay rate is faster.